# Counting the number of K4

Tags: graph-theory, clique

I was going over this [paper](http://theory.stanford.edu/~virgi/cs267/papers/klokskratschmuller.pdf) and I don't understand a certain proof (section five phase 2).

Given a graph *G=(V,E)* partitioned into the sets of vertices *L* and *H*. The vertices in *L* are at most *D* where *D* is an arbitrary number and the rest of the vertices are in *H*.

If we take a closer look at Phase 2 (Theorem 5). For each vertex *x* in *L* compute the square of the adjacency matrix of *G[N(x)]* to decide whether *G[N(x)]* contains a triangle.

We know that the fastest way to find a triangle in a graph is using fast matrix multiplication algorithm which is $O(n^\alpha)$. So, we can define a running time of $\sum_{x \epsilon L}^{ } d(x)^\alpha$. Since we know that *|L|* can be at most *e* (number of edges) if we choose a bad *D* and *d(x)* is at most *D*, why Phase 2 can be done in $O(D^{\alpha-1}e)$. I was under the impression that it was $O(D^{\alpha}e)$ i.e. where is the $\alpha-1$ coming from? I'm pretty sure it's trivial, but I'm missing the point.

Comment: This is a basic mathematic problem. If $x_1\ge x_2\ldots \ge x_n$ then $\Sigma x_i^\alpha \le x_1^{\alpha -1}\Sigma x_i$ for $\alpha \ge 1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sum of all degrees $d(x)$ in a graph is at most $2e$. The sum of all $d(x)^{\alpha}$ is at most $(max degree)^{\alpha -1}$ times sum of all $d(x)$. Together these give the upper bound.